# How to check if a matrix is antisymmetric

Tags: java, matrix, multidimensional-array

Here's my code to check if a matrix is antisymmetric. (A relation R on a set A is called antisymmetric if and only if for any a, and b in A, whenever (a,b) in R , and (b,a) in R , a = b must hold.)

```
// AntiSymmetric
public static boolean checkAntisymmetric(Graph graph, int vertices){
    boolean antisymmetric = false;
    for(int i = 1; i <= vertices; i++) {
        for(int j = 1; j <= vertices; j++){
            if((graph.getEdge(i, j) == graph.getEdge(j, i)) && (i == j)){
                antisymmetric = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    if(antisymmetric){
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

And my getEdge function is:

```
public int getEdge(int to, int from){
    try{
        return adjencencyMatrix[to][from];
    } catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException index){
        System.out.println("Vertices does not exist");
    }
    return -1;
}
```

For example, if I give the edges represented by pairs: (2,3) (3,5) (3,2) (5,1) (4,4)
It should be return false because of (4,4).
Additionally I used this as reference:[image: Representing Relations]

I was able to create a function in which checks if a matrix is indeed symmetric. The only thing different is that my anti-symmetric function has the condition (i == j) within the if statement. Could someone see why it's always returning true? Thanks.
An example Matrix I've been using to test the function is shown here:

```
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 1 0 0
0 1 0 0 1
0 0 0 0 0
1 0 0 0 0
```

For the pairs: (2,3) (3,5) (3,2) (5,1)

Comment: Deleted my answer, as "Antisymmetric" is not the oposite of "Symmetric" :-) (long long time ago...)

Comment: Thanks for your feedback!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asymmetry implies that for every i, j where i != j, M(i, j) == 0 or M(j, i) == 0.

Your current condition:

```
if((graph.getEdge(i, j) == graph.getEdge(j, i)) && (i == j))
```

Due to the `i == j` in your condition, you're checking the diagonal down the center of the matrix. This implies that `getEdge(i, j) == getEdge(i, i) == getEdge(j, j) == getEdge(j, i)`, since `i == j`. So your check will always pass since you're comparing a matrix entry to itself.

Try implementing the condition specified in the definition you provided, which basically states that one of the two must be `0`:

```
if((graph.getEdge(i, j) == 0 || graph.getEdge(j, i) == 0) && (i != j))
```

However, your logic for breaking out of the loop is flawed as well, since you'd return true if the first pair satisfies this condition rather than the whole matrix. Try checking for failures and exit early, otherwise if you make it through the matrix without failing then you know the condition was successful for each pair and the matrix is asymmetric:

```
// AntiSymmetric
public static boolean checkAntisymmetric(Graph graph, int vertices){
    for(int i = 1; i <= vertices; i++) {
        for(int j = 1; j <= vertices; j++){
            if((i != j) && graph.getEdge(i, j) != 0 && graph.getEdge(j, i) != 0) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

We essentially check to see if any pairs don't satisfy the condition.

Comment: This is helpful! I'll make some changes and see if I can figure out something.

Comment: Thanks! The code has finally been fixed! Now I have to work on transitive... which I think it's a lot hard hahahaha. I'll spend another 5 hours hahaha. Thanks a lot for your help.